# Download playlist from first video?

Tags: youtube-dl

Is it possible to download videos from Youtube playlist in reverse order? My Internet is due to be disconnected for a month in less than 24 hours and I would like to download as much content from a channel as possible. But, I want to start from the first video, instead of the last. This is because the videos are a tutorial series and you basically start from the first.

At the moment it's download from the last video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for anyone else looking:

```
youtube-dl --playlist-reverse https://www.youtube.com/user/smosh
```